# Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100003b

Tags: xamarin

why this exception raised. how to solve the exception

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> 09-15 15:00:05.973 E/mono    ( 5985):
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100003b
>   (from typeref, class/assembly Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IReferenceProvider,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null) 09-15 15:00:05.973 E/mono    ( 5985):   at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.7(intptr,intptr,intptr) 09-15
>   15:00:05.974 E/mono-rt ( 5985): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100003b
>   (from typeref, class/assembly Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IReferenceProvider,
>   Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null) 09-15 15:00:05.974 E/mono-rt ( 5985):   at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.7(intptr,intptr,intptr)

```
public partial class MenuPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: For sure you should ask a question...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Clean all
- Quit IDE
- Delete all bin/obj fodlers
- If on VS PC, delete on the linked MAC folder ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/builds

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. A clean and rebuild of the solution in Visual Studio rid me of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I cleaned the solution and rebuilt. During the clean it complained that it couldn't find some files in the obj directory but still built and run correctly.